# SQL Server query should return max value records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table like this:

```
id_Seq_No   emp_name     Current_Property_value  
-----------------------------------------------
1           John              100
2           Peter             200
3           Pollard            50
4           John              500
```

I want the max record value of particular employee.

For example, John has 2 records seq_no 1, 4. I want 4th seq_no Current_Property_Value in single query.

```
Select  
    max(id_Seq_No) 
from 
    t1 
where 
    emp_name = 'John'
```

Comment: If you want the maximum property value why are you using `max` on ID ? Why not `max(Current_Property_Value)` ? Did you mean latest instead of maximum perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos he wants the `Current_Property_value` for the "maximum" `id_Seq_No` matching a certain `emp_name`

Comment: @msanz that's not what the question or title says, although one could infer this. The title and text should be rewritten

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos totally agree with you, just tried to throw some light on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `Current_Property_value`, just order the results by `id_Seq_No` and get the first one:

```
SELECT
   TOP 1 Current_Property_value
FROM
   table
WHERE
   emp_name = 'John'
ORDER BY
   id_Seq_No DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

this will give highest for all tied employees

```
select top 1 with ties
id_Seq_No,emp_name,Current_Property_value 
from
table 
order by
row_number() over (partition by emp_name order by Current_Property_value desc)
```

Comment: You don't need TOP/ORDER BY when you use `ROW_NUMBER`, just check its value against 1 in the WHERE clause. You are forcing an unnecessary sort.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: just check its value against 1   ..? you mean using cte and check rownum=1

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos:Top is used with ties to restrict only top 1 elements after ordering by rownumber

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` with `CTE`.

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY emp_name
        ORDER BY id_Seq_No DESC
    ), * 
    FROM your_table_name
    WHERE emp_name = 'John'
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1;
```